# Python regular expression: search from right to left by delimiter, then search from right to left in the left part of the delimiter

Tags: python, regex

Example:

```
aaa_bbb_ /xyz=uvw,ccc=height:18y,weight:1xb,ddd=19d
```

The end goal is to parse it into a dictionary:

```
{'aaa_bbb_ /xyz':'uvw','ccc':'height:18y,weight:1xb','ddd':19d}
```

The rule is:

> search for "=" from the right, split by "=".
> To the left of the "=" sign, search for "," from right to left again, content between "," and "=" is the key: 'ddd', and content to the right of "=" is the value: '19d'.

After this is done, repeat the step in the remainder of the string

```
aaa_bbb_/xyz=uvw,ccc=height:18y,weight:1xb
```

The string contains at least one key:value pair(s). Character `,`, as well almost all special character, can exist in the value as the example suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import re

s = "aaa_bbb_ /xyz=uvw,ccc=height:18y,weight:1xb,ddd=19d"
res = re.findall(r"(.*?)=(.*?)(?:,|$)", s[::-1])
d = {k[::-1] : v[::-1] for v, k in res}
print(d)
```

It gives:

```
{'ddd': '19d', 'ccc': 'height:18y,weight:1xb', 'aaa_bbb_ /xyz': 'uvw'}
```